# How to convert datetime to day name and month name in erlang?

Tags: date, datetime, time, erlang, erlang-otp

How to get following **DateTime** in Erlang?
`Fri Jul 13 19:12:59 IST 2018`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL; DR**

Use the exceptional [`qdate`](https://github.com/choptastic/qdate/) for all your date/time formatting, converting, and timezone handling. Look at the [Demonstration](https://github.com/choptastic/qdate#demonstration) section in particular to get the gist, and adjust to your needs.

---

Erlang's date handling, in my opinion, is convoluted and lacking in the major functionality that's needed for proper date handling. It's getting better, but not quite there. Moreover, timezone handling is primitive at best.

`qdate`'s functions will take (almost) any date format and convert to any date format, while using either an implicit timezone (setting the timezone on a per-process basis), or by setting a specific timezone.

In any case, if you go custom, you will end up with something similar to this:

```
1> {{Year, Month, Day}, {Hour, Minute, Second}} = calendar:now_to_datetime(erlang:now()).
{{2018,7,13},{14,39,45}}
2> lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~4..0w-~2..0w-~2..0wT~2..0w:~2..0w:~2..0w",[Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second])).
"2018-07-13T14:39:45"
```

...not good ;)

Those are my two cents. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
A = calendar:universal_time().
qdate:to_string(<<"D M j G:i:s T Y">> , <<"IST">>,  A).
```

You can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for different formatting. Advisable to use only if you have to support legacy system because this function call use seems expensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_time() ->
        {{Year, Month, Day},{ Hour, Minute, Second}} = calendar:local_time(),
          DayOfWeek = calendar:day_of_the_week({Year, Month, Day}),
          DayName = day_check(DayOfWeek),
          MonthName = month_check(Month),
          lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~3..0s ~3..0s ~2..0w ~2..0w:~2..0w:~2..0w IST ~4..0w", [DayName, MonthName, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Year])).

day_check(1) -> 'Mon';
day_check(2) -> 'Tue';
day_check(3) -> 'Wed';
day_check(4) -> 'Thu';
day_check(5) -> 'Fri';
day_check(6) -> 'Sat';
day_check(7) -> 'Sun'.

month_check(1)  -> 'Jan';
month_check(2)  -> 'Feb';
month_check(3)  -> 'Mar';
month_check(4)  -> 'Apr';
month_check(5)  -> 'May';
month_check(6)  -> 'Jun';
month_check(7)  -> 'Jul';
month_check(8)  -> 'Aug';
month_check(9)  -> 'Sep';
month_check(10) -> 'Oct';
month_check(11) -> 'Nov';
month_check(12) -> 'Dec'.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).